# Can the same column have primary key & foreign key constraint to another column

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

Can the same column have primary key & foreign key constraint to another column?

```
Table1: ID - Primary column, foreign key constraint for Table2 ID
Table2: ID - Primary column, Name
```

Will this be an issue if i try to delete table1 data?

```
Delete from table1 where ID=1000;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You 'll find the answer into this link: [Can a database attribute be primary and foreign key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244432/can-a-database-attribute-be-primary-and-foreign-key)

Comment: You can create a column having both keys (primary and foreign) but then it will be one to one mapping and add uniqueness to this column.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There should be no problem with that. Consider the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(20)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
   id int PRIMARY KEY, 
   t2_id int, 
   FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES table2 (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, 'First Row');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2, 'Second Row');

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (4, 2);
```

The tables now contain:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+-------+
| id | t2_id |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     1 |
|  4 |     2 |
+----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM table2;
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | First Row  |
|  2 | Second Row |
+----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now we can successfully delete rows like this:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE t2_id = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

However we won't be able to delete the following:

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = 1;
ERROR 1451 (23000): A foreign key constraint fails
```

If we had defined the foreign key on `table1` with the [`CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) option, we would have been able to delete the parent, and all the children would get deleted automatically:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(20)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
   id int PRIMARY KEY, 
   t2_id int, 
   FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES table2 (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, 'First Row');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2, 'Second Row');

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (4, 2);
```

If we were to repeat the previously failed `DELETE`, the children rows in `table1` will be deleted as well as the parent row in `table2`:

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+-------+
| id | t2_id |
+----+-------+
|  4 |     2 |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM table2;
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  2 | Second Row |
+----+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but I do not see how this answers the question.  (And why it has been accepted.)  The question is asking whether we can have the same column have primary key & foreign key constraint to another column. The accepted answer introduces a second column (t2_id) as a foreign key, it does not show a column which is both primary key and foreign key.

Comment: And I thought I'll find the answer here :/

Comment: This answer is no where about the asked question. Don't know why it was accepted. I read full answer (a long one) considering this was the accepted answer and then found it of no relevance.

Answer (score 25):

Assigning Primary Key And Foreign key to the same column in a Table:

```
create table a1 (
    id1 int not null primary key 
);
insert into a1 values(1),(2),(3),(4);

create table a2 (
    id1 int not null primary key foreign key references a1(id1)
);
insert into a2 values(1),(2),(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Jason may have worked some time in the past but when I tried to use this answer in 2021 against a MySQL 5.7 server it complains. The syntax I used to get this working was;

```
CREATE TABLE a1 (
    id1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO a1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

CREATE TABLE a2 (
    id1 INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id1),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_id1` FOREIGN KEY (id1) REFERENCES a1(id1)
);
INSERT INTO a2 VALUES (1),(2),(3);
```

For one-to-one relationships of this type, I would also strongly recommend you create the foreign keys as;

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_id1` FOREIGN KEY (id1) REFERENCES a1(id1) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it can.

No, it won't.

*P.S. But you'll not be able to delete table2 data without deleting corresponding table1 rows obviously.*

*P.P.S. I've implemented such structure in Postgres, but it must be similar for MySQL.*