# customize django admin object detail page url(object change url)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to override the default django admin change url.
In my table i have ***composite primary key***.

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey('PQR', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='code', primary_key=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Languages, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='language')
    me_name = models.TextField()
    common_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    abbreviation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'abc'
        unique_together = (('code', 'language'), ('language', 'me_name'),)
```

Now my admin url in django admin for each object is /admin/home/abc/{{code}}/change/.
But i have repeated codes in objects because primary key is composite of ('code', 'language'). So for objects which have repeated code are throwing

```
Error
    MultipleObjectsReturned at /admin/home/abc/X00124/change/
    get() returned more than one ABC -- it returned 2!
```

here X00124 this code associated with more than one object.

**What i want here that override the modeladmins get_urls() method and construct the url /admin/home/abc/{{code}}/{{language}}/change/.**

I tried but no success. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that for solve it, you need to change admin URLs? Because after it, you should change admin template too. I think will be better create function in `AdminModel` class which will be resolve language code, and returning only one element, that you need

Comment: any reference for to create function in AdminModel?

Comment: I'm wondering about how a `primary_key` column can have duplicates.

Comment: @SivasubramaniamArunachalam it is possible

Comment: @AndMar Very interesting. Can you provide more details about how that is possible and with Django too?

Comment: @SivasubramaniamArunachalam https://stackoverflow.com/a/9244480/4900574

Comment: is it possible to add get perems to each objects change url? like /admin/home/abc/{{code}}/change/?lang=English in list view only.

Comment: @Gaurav How will you choice language what will be in `query parameter`?

Comment: That's what i want to know.

Answer (score 0):

I made a virtual key, that represents compound key as a single value, that allows to use Django admin without code changes -

https://viewflow.medium.com/the-django-compositeforeignkey-field-get-access-to-a-legacy-database-without-altering-db-tables-74abc9868026