# Foreign key as primary key?

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have 2 tables `STUDENTS` and `SUBJECTS`. I need to create another table for `ENROLLMENTS`, the thing is that in that table I need to know the minimal attendance, which is both dependent on student (if he has a job it will be lower) and on subject (each subject has a base minimal attendance). Should I create another table like `MINIMAL_ATTENDACE` which holds the base minimal attendance of each Subject ? If so, is it good to have the primary key in that table be also the primary key from `SUBJECTS` ?

For example I have :

```
--STUDENTS--

ID  NAME  HIRED

1   Paul    1


--SUBJECTS--

ID  NAME  NUMBER_OF_TESTS  M_ATTENDANCE

1   Math        2              10


--ENROLLMENTS--

ID  STUDID  SUBID   M_ATTENDANCE
1      1       1        7 (Because Student is hired)
```

Comment: Can you paste in the "create table" code, or ddl of your existing takes, please?

Comment: See also: [Can a database attribute be primary and foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9244432/880990).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired rsults.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the question with my desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a several constraints on a single column.  Apparently, there is a many-to-many relationship between STUDENT and SUBJECT.  A possible approach for implementing this (with SQL) is an "intersection" or "bridge" table is.  You can use a composite PK, and foreign key constraints like this:

[image]

**Demo ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da86f123f8f11bd080f01f38a225e842))**

```
-- parent tables (and test data)
create table students (id primary key, name, hired)
as
select 1, 'Paul', 1 from dual union all
select 2, 'Maggie', 1 from dual union all
select 3, 'Herbert', 0 from dual ;

create table subjects (id primary key, name, number_of_tests, attendance_standard, attendance_hired)
as
select 100, 'Maths', 2, 10, 7 from dual union all
select 200, 'Biology', 3, 12, 8 from dual union all
select 300, 'Physics' 2, 10, 8 from dual ;

-- intersection
create table enrollments(
  studentid number references students( id )
, subjectid number references subjects( id )
, constraint enrollments_pk primary key( studentid, subjectid )
) ;

-- test data for the "intersection" table: 
-- every student needs to complete every subject
insert into enrollments
select S.id, SUB.id
from students S cross join subjects SUB ;
```

In the example (above), we assume that {1} the "hired" attribute belongs to a STUDENT, and {2} the different "attendance" attributes are attributes of SUBJECT.

You can now just join the 3 tables, and find the required attendance for each student using the query below.

```
-- Get the attendance requirements for each student & their chosen subject
select 
  S.name, S.hired
, SUB.name
, case 
    when S.hired = 1 then SUB.attendance_hired
    else SUB.attendance_standard
  end as attendance_required
from students S
  join enrollments E on S.id = E.studentid
  join subjects SUB  on SUB.id = E.subjectid 
;

-- output
NAME    HIRED   NAME    ATTENDANCE_REQUIRED
Paul    1       Maths   7
Maggie  1       Maths   7
Herbert 0       Maths   10
Paul    1       Biology 8
Maggie  1       Biology 8
Herbert 0       Biology 12
Paul    1       Physics 8
Maggie  1       Physics 8
Herbert 0       Physics 10
```

If the "hire" status of a STUDENT can change during an academic year (or semester), you'd probably need to add some more entities (and subsequently: tables) for keeping track of each STUDENT's hire state change.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is as simple as you describe, it would be sufficient if the subject has two minimal attendences, ie. one for students with, and one for students without jobs.

Comment: Would that be a good practice though? Since my ENROLLEMNTS would point to an irrelevant column and I would constantly need to decide which one to use.

Comment: The computer could make that decision for you.  All you need is to indicate on the student if he or she has a job.  What is the "irrelevant column" ?

Comment: I think it would be irrelevant that my ENROLLMENTS would point to both values of attendance and I'm thinking when I extract data from ENROLLMENTS I would need to specify which columns from SUBJECTS I actually need (e.g attendance of hired students)

Comment: I think you need to brush up your knowledge of RDBMS.  Enrollments would "point" to subject, not to columns of a subject.

Comment: Well yes, but it would point to the whole table, of which I don't need one column. I'm new to DBs but I'm assuming that would be worse than pointing let's say to a table of which I need all the columns from.

Comment: Please Paul, learn a little about RDBMS.  Your assumption makes no sense.  A "foreign key" points to a single record of a parent table.  It may be sufficient to specify the table, then the DB knows it is the record of the parent table with the primary key that is stored in the child table.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `primary key` also a `foreign key`, in order to enforce the rule that the second table does not have an element which is missing from the first table. However, mixing up `foreign key` with `primary key` this way is usually a bad idea, because your rule might change. It is customary to make a field of a composite `primary key` also a `foreign key` particularly in many-to-many tables, but unless you are worried of storage space, you might want to create a `foreign key` on a separate field, so you will have less worries if your rule changes.

However, what you intend to store can be computed with aggregation, you do not necessarily need a separate `table` for that. You just `group by` and `select min`. You might also create a `view` if that's better, or, if changes on the main `table` are frequent, then you might consider the creation of a `materialized view`.