# Can we use same column in SQL as Primary Key and Foreign Key?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can a single column used as a primary and a foreign key at a time and kindly check the code as well!

```
Create table student
(
    s_id int primary key,
    s_name char(10),
    s_address varchar(12), 

    constraint fk1 foreign key (s_id) references student (s_id)
);
```

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: MS Access gives an error "Can not create relation between a field and itself"

Comment: Duplicate: Here's a [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774923/can-the-same-column-have-primary-key-foreign-key-constraint-to-another-column)

Comment: @AdeelYounas You should specify which database you're using (e.g. MySQL/Postgres/Sqlite/oracle/MS SQL, etc.), otherwise you'll get potentially misleading answers. edit: I see that marc_s added the ms-access tag, thanks.

Comment: @MaxGabriel i am using MYSQL!

Comment: @GVashist I am afraid that the answer that you suggest as duplicate is not really an answer. (See my comment to that answer.)

Comment: I don't see the point having the primary key of a table reference itself. Are you attempting to reference another table, e.g. `student <--> foo` with a constraint like `constraint fk1 foreign key (s_id) references foo (id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far i know, MS access doesnt allow creation of self joins and relations on same table. How ever to achieve this, you need to drag two copies of the student table into the Relationships screen, and then drag s_id from one onto s_id in the other. You have just defined a self join. I hope this works in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i tried on oracle and it says table created. so Yes if you are using oracle and should work fine with MySQL. This is mainly used for self reference queries.

Comment: I'd tried this in Ms Access but it didnt work for me!

Comment: Cant say about MS access. Probably because ms access is not a fully relational database system. Not sure though. But it works fine for Oracle and MySQL